# Computing $\int \frac{-\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

First I complete the square $$ax^2+bx+c = a\left(\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}\right)$$

and let $d=\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}$. Then $$\int \frac{-\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int \frac{-\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{\left(x^2+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\frac{d}{a}}}$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int \frac{-\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{a}{d}\right)\left(x^2+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+1}}$$

Let $u=\sqrt{\frac{a}{d}}\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)$. Then $\mathrm{d}u=\sqrt{\frac{a}{d}}\ \mathrm{d}x$ and the integral becomes

$$\frac{\sqrt{d}}{a}\int\frac{-\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{u^2+1}}$$

But I don't think this is right. Ultimately I'm looking for an answer in terms of inverse trigonometric functions, hopefully, $\arccos u$ depending on $a,b,c$. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you're happy with inverse hyperbolic trig, this is perfectly fine.

Comment: It looks like you're assuming that the quadratic is positive everywhere (which is a condition on the discriminant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the signs of $a$ and $b^2-4ac$, you can reduce the function under the radical to one of

$$u^2+1,u^2-1\text{ or }1-u^2.$$

The corresponding antiderivatives are

$$\text{arsinh }u,\text{arcosh }u\text{ or }\arcsin u.$$

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit. What theorem are you referring to here?

Comment: @variations: I am using no theorem. Just obvious discussion based on your own computation.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{\sqrt{d}}{a} \int \frac{-du}{\sqrt{u^{2}+1}}$.
Currently I can see only solution $\sqrt{u^{2}+1} =t - u$
$u=\frac{t^{2} - 1}{2t}. \sqrt{u^{2}+1} = \frac{t^{2}+1}{2t}, du=\frac{t^{2} + 1}{2t^{2}}$
$\int \frac{-du}{\sqrt{u^{2}+1}} = -\int \frac{dt}{t} = -ln|t|+C = -ln|u+\sqrt{u^2+1}| + C$